# Darlington transistor for driving coils

Tags: pic, driver, coil, darlington

I try to drive two small pcb coils. The coils have a resistance of around 14 Ohms (i dont know the L value). I have a PIC10F200 controlling the base of a BCV27. However i dont seem to get much more than 0.1V across the coils.
Did i make a mistake, or is there something fundamentally wrong with my approach?

Thanks!!
[image]

Comment: Probably something fundamentally wrong but, you haven’t stated what your aim is.

Comment: What is your VDD voltage, and does it stay steady when you turn Q1 on?  Your diode should be from the collector to VDD to prevent inductive kick, BTW -- you may have killed your transistor on the first try and now you're just seeing that.

Comment: Report every node until Ohm’s law and the datasheet conflict

Comment: If the transistor is operational, similar [values](https://imgur.com/a/jPqJ7Ln) ​​should be measured at each point. The base current is unnecessarily high. R1 could be of much greater value.

Comment: 1&3 backwards on U1?

Answer (score 0):

A fundamental error involves D1. Its anode should go to Q1's collector, not to GND.

A capacitor should be added from +5V DC supply to GND. This is not a fundamental error. But it will keep transient voltages from destroying your processor, and act as a local charge reservoir that will give your solenoid more "punch": something in the hundred(s) of microfarads.
When a solenoid is switched off, its stored energy dumps via D1 into the DC supply. The capacitor absorbs this energy and keeps the DC supply from momentarily rising...even a short transient above that which the processor can stand will cause destruction.

This processor seems to have 4 GPIO pins, one of which you are using to activate the solenoid. The other three pins are left open-circuit: their default state is to be GPIO input pins. Leaving high-resistance input pins floating is not good practice. Either change them to be outputs, or tie them to known logic states (high or low).